# how to install new os on mac pro without keyboard or mouse

Tags: macos

I deleted everything on the mac pro, it now can't even boot to login screen.

I also removed the wireless keyboard and mouse, used them on other device.

I think I can get a wired USB nouse to connect to it, but about the wired mac keyboard, I'm afraid it's hard to find. Any way I can do this with a window keyboard?

[image]

Comment: The easiest and most practicable solution for sure is to get *any* USB mouse and keyboard that works.

Comment: You don't need mac specific keyboards or mice any will do.